# Javascript filter cachedata

Tags: javascript

How can i filter the `Event_Type` ? what I want is to get the value of `Event_Type` which is the `MT`

this is my current code

```
        if (cachedData) {
            let cachedDatas = JSON.parse(cachedData);
            for (var data in cachedDatas) {
                var keys = data == 'Event_Type' ? 'R150274705' : data;
                console.log("keys", keys)
                let code = data.filter((val) => {
                    return cachedDatas['Event_Type'] == val.code;
                })
            }
        }
```

this is the data

```
{"Event_Type":"MT","Subject":"","startDate":"07/05/2022 11:43 AM","startDateRaw":"2022-05-07T03","description":""}
```

Comment: You have used `for..in` which loops over the object keys, try `for..of`. Also, `filter` is an array type method,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a very simple solution like this?

```js
const jsonStr='{"Event_Type":"MT","Subject":"","startDate":"07/05/2022 11:43 AM","startDateRaw":"2022-05-07T03","description":""}';

console.log(JSON.parse(jsonStr).Event_Type);
```